# Is there a way to have a Bulma dropdown not be hidden by overflow: scroll of the wrapping div

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have a Bulma dropdown inside a scrolling div, but i want the dropdown to ignore the boundaries of the surrounding div.

So i know that this is possible with some trickery using position fixed, but i don't get it to work.
I also don't want to opt out of the bulma dropdown, if even possible.

I made this codepen to visualise my problem:

https://codepen.io/meneman/pen/BaQLVwd

In the HTML i have a wrapping div, which has overflow set to scroll and an inner-div, which is bigger that the outer div and acts as the scrolling content. Also this div contains a dropdown which when active i want to be visible above all divs.

```
<html>
  <body>
    
<div id="scroll-wrapper">
  <div id="inner-wrapper">
    <!-- replace is-active with is-hoverable to have actual dropdown-->
  <div class="dropdown is-active"> 
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu2">
      <span>Content</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu2" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        <p>You can insert <strong>any type of content</strong> within the dropdown menu.</p>
      </div>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        <p>You simply need to use a <code>&lt;div&gt;</code> instead.</p>
      </div>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        This is a link
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  </div>
</div>
    
    </html>
  </body>
```

css:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#scroll-wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 200px;
  width :300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
}

#inner-wrapper {
  
  height: 300px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set overflow to scroll, it will hide its contents that overflow. The `overflow-y:scroll` elements need to *not* be the parent element of the dropdown, but of the content that you want to hide.

If you want to hide all content but the dropdown, then the element with `overflow-y:scroll` needs to be an element that does not cover the dropdown.

One way to do this would be to place the box and the dropdown on the same position, but the box would be a sibling element to the dropdown, and the dropdown would be `position:absolute` over it, using a container to give them both a position to stick to.

```
positioned container
╚═button container with overflow-y:scroll
  ╚═button
╚═dropdown with position-absolute
```

Then you can do something like

```css
#dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 7px;
}
```

this way you keep the button above the dropdown that it controls, but the dropdown is a sibling, so it does not get overflow-limited by the button's direct container.

Comment: Visual example please :D

Comment: Sorry mang, I'm under the mood these last couple of months and won't be doing tech support until I'm feeling better.